# Simplify this jQuery-Code with a lot of selectors

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

how can i **simplify this code?** The Mouse-Events are all quite similar. Therefore there should be a way to shorten the code.

THANKS, 
Johannes

```
 var $allItems   = $('ul.image-grid li'),
    $kindertanzItems  = $('li[data-type=kindertanz]'),
    $urbanItems   = $('li[data-type=urban]'),
    $ethnoItems   = $('li[data-type=ethno]'),
    $gesundheitItems  = $('li[data-type=gesundheit]');


   $kindertanzItems.hover(function(){
    $allItems.each(function(){
     $(this).css("opacity","0.1"); 
    });
    $kindertanzItems.each(function(){
     $(this).css("opacity","1").css("background-color","#232628").css("border-color", "black"); 
    });
   }).mouseleave(function(){
    $allItems.each(function(){
     $(this).css("opacity","1"); 
    });
    $kindertanzItems.each(function(){
     $(this).css("background-color","#33373b").css("border-color", "#222527"); 
    });
   });


   $urbanItems.hover(function(){
    $allItems.each(function(){
     $(this).css("opacity","0.1"); 
    });
    $urbanItems.each(function(){
     $(this).css("opacity","1").css("background-color","#232628").css("border-color", "#101011"); 
    });
   }).mouseleave(function(){
    $allItems.each(function(){
     $(this).css("opacity","1"); 
    });
    $urbanItems.each(function(){
     $(this).css("background-color","#33373b").css("border-color", "#222527"); 
    });
   });


   $ethnoItems.hover(function(){
    $allItems.each(function(){
     $(this).css("opacity","0.1"); 
    });
    $ethnoItems.each(function(){
     $(this).css("opacity","1").css("background-color","#232628").css("border-color", "black"); 
    });
   }).mouseleave(function(){
    $allItems.each(function(){
     $(this).css("opacity","1"); 
    });
    $ethnoItems.each(function(){
     $(this).css("background-color","#33373b").css("border-color", "#222527"); 
    });
   });


   $gesundheitItems.hover(function(){
    $allItems.each(function(){
     $(this).css("opacity","0.1"); 
    });
    $gesundheitItems.each(function(){
     $(this).css("opacity","1").css("background-color","#232628").css("border-color", "#101011"); 
    });
   }).mouseleave(function(){
    $allItems.each(function(){
     $(this).css("opacity","1"); 
    });
    $gesundheitItems.each(function(){
     $(this).css("background-color","#33373b").css("border-color", "#222527"); 
    });
   });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're only applying styles - therefore you should be using CSS not Javascript.

Create a CSS file and add the following:

```
ul.image-grid:hover {
   /* Opacity and color rules for whole ul in here */
}
```

And instead of identifying `<li>`s by their data-type, you should add classes to them, so you can do:

```
ul.image-grid > li.kindertanz:hover {
   /* Opacity and color rules for this li in here */
}
```

---

Update: The requirement is to highlight not only whichever `<li>` the mouse is hovering over, but also every other `<li>` with the same `data-type`. The Javascript to do this is:

```
var $allItems = $("ul.image-grid li");

// Notice that hover() can take two functions,
// one for mouseenter, one for mouseleave
$allItems.hover(function () {
   // Mouseenter
   $allItems.css("opacity", "0.1"); // No need for each(),
                                    // jquery will apply to all elements

   // Depending on your jquery version...
   // If you're using jQuery 1.4.3+ you can do this:
   var type = $(this).data("type");
   // If you're using jQuery 1.4.2 and below, you have to do this:
   var type = $(this).attr("data-type");

   // Get all items of the same type
   $("li[data-type=" + type + "]").css({
       // You can set multiple CSS rules in one go like this
       "opacity": "1",
       "background-color": "#232628",
       "border-color": "black"
   });
}, function () {
   // Do something similar on mouseleave
});
```

Hope that finally helps!

Sidenote: while the above will work, I'd recommend setting a CSS class for the highlighted state. That way instead of messing with all the CSS attributes in your javascript, you can simply do `.removeClass("highlight")` for all items, and `.addClass("highlight")` for the others.

Comment: The advantage of this method is that it will work faster, and not need to wait for onReady or any states like that.

Comment: There will be more than four different data-types, because they are dynamically added with a CMS. It’s quite hard for me produce a CSS-Class for every data-type with the CMS.  

Therefor i have to find all different data-types in all <li>-tags dynamically with jQuery and then add the hover functionality to them … !??

Comment: @Johannes Scherg - Ok the real question then is, how many different border colours do you need? If you only need one, then you need one class for all the li's, or even an ID for the ul,  but if you need two or more then you need that many classes...

Comment: @box9 — I only need one border-color. It’s a kind of active state. Thanks

Comment: @Johannes Scherg - Right, in that case, you'd still do everything in CSS, but you won't need to specify the data-type. In my second block of code, just do `ul.image-grid > li:hover {` and anything you put in there will apply to any `li` when it's hovered over. Remember, whenever you can, use CSS for layout and look, while javascript is for more complex behaviour.

Comment: Probably i expressed imprecisely, i wanna give you an example: I have a user-defined amount of `li` items. Each of this items exists *more than one-times*. When the user hovers one of the `li` items all other items which belong to the hovered item (originally the same data-type) should blink, too. I belive i can not do that with CSS only, as i use a CMS.

Comment: @Johannes Scherg - Ok, I think I finally understand :) I'll update my answer... with javascript this time ;)

Comment: *Thank you very much!!* I will test it tomorrow and then hopefully mark this question as solved ;-)